# Conversion of Oracle Query to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, postgresql, pentaho-data-integration

I am posting a part of my query which is in Oracle and it as follows:

```
cast(from_tz(cast((Select max(d.startdate) from Public.result_slalom d 
               where d.eventid = a.eventid 
               and d.modifydate = (Select max(e.modifydate) from result_slalom e 
                where e.eventid = d.eventid)) as timestamp), 'Asia/Calcutta') at Time Zone 'Europe/Berlin' as date) as OpenLastTime,
```

I want to run this query on PostgreSQL. So I wrote a query which looks like this for PostgreSQL:

```
(Select Cast(to_timestamp(max(d.startdate)) 
                      from Public.result_slalom d 
               where d.eventid = a.eventid 
               and d.modifydate = (Select max(e.modifydate) from Public.result_slalom e
                where e.eventid = d.eventid) as timestamp, 'Asia/Calcutta') at Time Zone 'Europe/Berlin' as date) as OpenLastTime,
```

I am getting a few errors here and there, which I believe are related to some bracket issues. Or due to the keyword 'timestamp' in the second select clause for e.modifydate.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: This will not work in either database because `a` is not defined.  I would suggest that you simplify your actual query and then rephrase the question or ask another.

Comment: What exactly are the "few errors here and there" you get? Sorry for asking, but my crystal ball is broken.

Answer (score 0):

In the future, please try to include a **full reproducible example** that we can actually run. I made [an example fiddle that shows how you could do this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/252f0/1).

`from_tz` is not a Postgres function. Also, the `date` type in Postgres does not have a time or timezone component - it's just year-month-day. Your `startdate` and `modifydate` columns will need to be of type `timestamp`.

Here's my conversion:

```
select ((Select max(d.startdate) from result_slalom d 
           where d.eventid = a.eventid and 
           d.modifydate = (Select max(e.modifydate) from result_slalom e 
             where e.eventid = d.eventid)) at time zone 'Asia/Calcutta') 
        at Time Zone 'Europe/Berlin' as OpenLastTime
from a;
```